# Search database with textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, listview, search

First of all I am working at VB 2012.

I have problem with searching my database. It goes so slow, actually filling the `ListView` is what bothers me.
I have a text box with TextChange event. Its instant search. So when I'm starting to write in that text box it's starts to filter the database and filling the data in the `ListView`.

This is the code in `text box` and the `Load` procedure

```
Private Sub txtID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtID.TextChanged
    Load("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '" & txtID.Text & "%'")
End Sub


Private Sub Load(ByVal strQ As String)
    List.Items.Clear()
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQ, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        While dr.Read
            Dim X As ListViewItem
            X = List.Items.Add(dr(0))
            X.SubItems.Add(dr(2))
            X.SubItems.Add(dr(3))
            X.SubItems.Add(dr(4))
            X.SubItems.Add(dr(1))
            X.SubItems.Add(dr(5))            
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

So, every time I hit a letter it calls the load procedure.

And I have so much data and it goes so slow. Can you help me somehow ? Is there any solution ?

Comment: You're performing a search against the database every time someone presses a key? And wondering why it's slow?

Comment: Don't yell at me. That's why I asked for an idea :(

Comment: @GigaC trust me, he is not yelling at you. You would know if Aaron yelled.

Comment: Kidding :))))
I know that what I am doing is funny and noobish, but at the beginning the database was so small and I had no problem. Suddenly the database got bigger and bigger....

Comment: hehehe... @GigaC,... have you solved it out?

Comment: yeah :) @gumuruh
this was long time ago :D

Comment: @GigaC, my case that was pretty similar to this is ended by a simple answer to use an ArrayList or related data type variables, then store every data loaded from DB into it, then search based on that List rather than connecting & reconnecting into the DB. good for small size DB i think, wouldn't u think so?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're ever going to possibly speed that up. Connecting and querying the database is a lot of overhead, especially compared to the speed of pressing a key or typing a word. There's just not a way to do this without severely affecting the user who's typing.

What I suggest instead is that you wait for the user to tell you they're done typing before you bother making a search. If you're trying to do fancy auto-completion stuff you're going to need to cache the data a lot closer to the app than the database.

Comment: That would be a problem. I need instant search (auto-complete), not after the user type the whole word and hit enter. You got the picture ? :)
Anyway, at the beginning I am loading all the contacts and fill the ListView. Can I filter the ListView instead of the database ?

Comment: @GigaC That conflicts with what you said in your question (filling the data in the ListView happens later). Anyway that's what I mean by "caching the data a lot closer to the app"... if you're having problems filtering an already populated ListView, then maybe you should be asking that question, coherently, instead. *shrug*

Comment: What I wanted to say is that at the load of the form I must fill the whole data in the ListView from the database. But the search I was doing with the same method(getting the data from database over and over again). Nevermind, just tell me can I filter already filled ListView with LINQ method. I just read about it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class to hold the search results, like this:

```
Public Class SearchResult
    Private _propID As String
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return _propID
        End Get
        Set
            _propID = Value
        End Set
    End Property

Private _propName As String
    Public Property PropName() As String
        Get
            Return _propName
        End Get
        Set
            _propName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

Now you query the database to get all the results to display in the list view, storing it in a `List(Of SearchResult)`, like this:

```
Private Function Load(ByVal strQ As String) As List(Of SearchResult)
    Dim ListOfResults = New List(Of SearchResult)
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQ, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        While dr.Read
            Dim X As New SearchResult()
            X.PropID = dr(0)
            X.PropName = dr(1)
            ...            
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

You can call this code like this:

```
Dim AllSearchResults = Load("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '" & txtID.Text & "%'")
```

Now when you want to do a search you can apply the following LINQ against your cached list of everything (`AllSearchResults`), like this:

```
Public Function DoSearch(searchText As String) As List(Of SearchResult)    
    Return From s In AllSearchResults Where s.PropID.Contains(searchText) Select c
End Function
```

Finally, you can call this LINQ filtering on each key press by the user, like this:

```
Private Sub txtID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtID.TextChanged
    DoSearch(txtID.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude....awesome, if this works I will find you and kiss you !!
I will try the code right now !

Comment: Added a return type of `As List(Of SearchResult)` to the `DoSearch` function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to cut the overhead down by a fair degree to to wait to issue the query until the length of the text entered is 3 (or better yet 5) characters.  It is very, very unlikely that all customers (or whatever these are) starting with 'S' is going to be meaningful or helpful to anyone except the one person on rare occasions looking for "Sab....". People HAVE to be typing in the 2nd and 3rd char before the first query is complete and displayed!

To try to make a really bad idea less bad, I'd look into a way to issue the query ONCE (on the first character if I really, really has to), then filter those results down on subsequent keystrokes.  (ala Aaron's "caching the data a lot closer to the app").

The next thing is `Select *`.  I dunno whats in the table, but do you REALLY need every column?  This appears to be some sort of pick list, do you really need 6 fields to provide the user the information needed to make a selection?  If there are more than 6 columns in the table, immediately narrow the query to the 6 used in the listview.  Once they make their choice you can go back and get exactly what you need by ID or whatever.

I'd personally use a faster control but thats subjective.

ALL databases eventually acquire dormant data.  Customers (or whatever) that were one time shoppers and never return - do they need to be in the list?  If there is a column somewhere for lastorderdate or lastupdateddate construct your query to pick those active in the last XX months (and if not, see if you can add one because the issue is not going to get better as the database gets larger!).  Then a checkbox for the user to widen the range as needed, like "See All" or something.  Users are not likely to balk at the idea if it speeds things up the other 80% of the time.

...those are just off the top of my head.